# Send post data to another page in my wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, post, wordpress-theming

i am migrating some web apps to a new wordpress site, I am migrating them to wordpress plugins and I am new to wordpress plugins creation, I need to create a wordpress plugin that sends post data to another pages (they are part of the plugin) and do something.

Example:

User selects an item from a select and clicks "Send" button (start.php) and another page (dostuff.php) catches the POST data and does something with that and then shows a list of files or other things.

How can I do this?

I have already created a shortcode and display the start page in a post in my wordpress site, but how can I send the data to the dostuff.php page and manipulate it?

Thanks :)